# Which encryption algorithm is used in php openssl_public_encrypt

Tags: php, openssl, android, asymmetric

I am looking for exact algorithm that is used in PHP's `openssl_public_encrypt` function, as I need to encrypt some data in android app with that, and I couldnt find android equivalent of PHP's `openssl_public_encrypt`.

(I am not sure, but I think its RSA, but when I tried to encrypt data using RSA in android and decrypt it using PHP's `openssl_private_decrypt`, its not working) Or if anyone can help with, which function/method should I use in android for this.

Comment: this is more of a PHP programming question than a security question as you are asking about how a particular library functions

Comment: did you look to the source? https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/openssl  or https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/8baf12b1615e8a89d984f8df8d9585d1e434f6c6/ext/openssl/openssl.c

Comment: according to the source, it uses the function `RSA_public_encrypt` which is from OpenSSL: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:RSA_public_encrypt(3)

Comment: If you want to know how an open source program works, always look to the code